# What is relaxation technique of SV tran gates?

Tags: system-verilog

IEEE Std 1800™-2012 section 4.9.5 says "Switch processing shall consider all the devices in a bidirectional switch-connected net before it can
determine the appropriate value for any node on the net because the inputs and outputs interact. A simulator can do this using a relaxation technique."

What is this relaxation technique the LRM is referring to? Where can I read the detailed relaxation algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

A bidirectional switch is inherently an analog device. Trying to simulate this kind of device in a discrete event based digital simulator creates quite a challenge. This device can create many event feedback loops and the relaxation algorithm is there to prevent endless zero-delay loops of evaluation. The standard does not specify the actual implementation of this algorithm, but most simulators use ones derived from [this paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a444290.pdf) by Randy Bryant.