# Verilog tranif1 nmos simultion speed

Tags: verilog

I know that tranif1(0) is bidirectional primitive
 and nmos is unidirectional primitive.
 In the aspect of simulation speed, is there a difference between nmos and tranif1 ?

For example, nmos is faster than tranif1 because unidirectional primitive simulation calculation is half of bidirectional primitive.

Is this right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you investigated? Add also a minimal code example.

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional switch simulation can be an order of magnitude slower than unidirectional. It depends on how many bi- switches can be optimized to uni- switches, and the total number of bi- switches making up a single network.

See this [related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55983740/2755607).